# Date conversion is returning an old date in javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I have an API which returns date values. Sample value is like 1521441000. When I formatted the date using javascript, I am getting Jan 18 1970 08:07 PM. Also I tried using Javascript Date function. Then also the same reply. Please see the console screen shot. As per the expectation I want this months(March - April 2018) date. Which I am fitering using API call. This is a third party API.I want to confirm is this the problem with API.

[image]

Why this is happening. Is this the problem with the date which is returned from the API? Or Is there any problem in my comparison?

Comment: multiply by 1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1521441000` is time in seconds, you need to multiply that by 1000 to get miliseconds before passing to moment/date constructor:

```js
console.log(new Date(1521441000));
console.log(new Date(1521441000 * 1000));
```